# Can I use the RV-3028-C7 INT pin as a PSW switch?

Tags: power, gate-driving

The RV-1805-C3 has a PSW pin that can be configured as an output switch. The RV-3028-C7 does not have such a pin, it only has an INT pin.

I need to periodically power ON my MCU, do stuff, and then turn it off. Before turning it off configure the RV-3028-C7 to wake at a certain time.
[image]

Can I configure the INT pin on the RV-3028-C7 as a PSW switch? Or do I need to use the RV-1805-C3 for this particular case?

the application manual for the RV-3028-C7 can be found here:
https://www.microcrystal.com/fileadmin/Media/Products/RTC/App.Manual/RV-3028-C7_App-Manual.pdf

and the application manual for the RV-1805-C3 can be found here:
https://www.microcrystal.com/fileadmin/Media/Products/RTC/App.Manual/RV-1805-C3_App-Manual.pdf

Comment: Please provide a link to a data sheet that gives full details of the pins you are considering using. Also note that this device does not appear to be recommended for new designs. Please also add a circuit proposal showing how you would like to use it.

Comment: Added what you asked....

Comment: In the -C3 manual, the PSW pin is associated with the Sleep Control register. The -C7 manual omits this register; in fact, the string “sleep control” doesn’t occur at all. It looks like this functionality has been removed.

Comment: thank you @DoxyLover .  To me, that's a really useful and important functionality.  With the -C3 being not advised for new designs one must ask what IC alternatives exist with similar dimensions and number of components.